# How to make git log show entire commit -- even the "uninteresting" parts?

Tags: git

In the output of "git log -U0", Git appears to hide the diffs it deems "uninteresting". How do I force git to show the entire diff as displayed in the "git show" message for every commit in the log? I tried using --full-history, but it's still hiding parts of the diff.

Is this possible? Or do I just need to get every commit and then individually do "git show" on each hash?

Thanks!

Comment: `git diff abcde abcde~1` perhaps (with abcde being a commit sha)?

Comment: Can you share an example of such output and explain what part git reducted even though you wanted to show it?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking at *merge commits*? The `-p` or other diff output from `git log` is normally suppressed entirely for such commits, while `git show` defaults to `--cc` style.

Comment: Collin, I can just do git show abcde individually to get the diff, but I want to be able to get ALL of the diffs if one command if possible for performance reasons -- this is for a script.  Mureinik, in the git show there is a diff like this @@ -3 +3 @@ - line 1 + line b followed by another diff, but in git log that diff is missing. And Torek, --unified automatically includes the patch -- but I have tried with -p and it doesn't add anything more.

Comment: My point is that `-U` (or anything else that triggers patch generation) still does not turn on patch generation for merge commits. If those are the ones that you are concerned with—which is something I still don't know— *if* these are the ones of concern, you need to know several things about the way merge commits are shown.

Comment: Can you give an example for missing diff?

Comment: Hey Torek, this is not a merge commit. Just a regular everyday commit. Thanks!